# Могу ли я создать цикл для изменения содержимого элементов коллекции js?

Tags: javascript

Js

```
listElem = document.querySelectorAll('.list__item');

listElem[0].innerHTML = `One`;
listElem[1].innerHTML = `Two`;
listElem[2].innerHTML = `Three`;
```

HTML

```
  <ul class="list">
        <li class="list__item">Пункт1</li>
        <li class="list__item">Пункт2</li>
        <li class="list__item">Пункт3</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Так а в чём конкретно вопрос? "Могу ли я создать цикл" надо спрашивать себя, а не нас.

Comment: Вы хотите присвоить трём пунктам одно значение и спрашиваете, как это сделать в одну сточку, а не в три? Если я неправильно понял задачу, уточните.

Comment: Я понял свою ошибку , спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Ваш пример не совсем подходит для циклов, потому что в нём присваиваются значения, которые невозможно автоматизировать в цикле. Но вот простой пример, где это возможно:

```js
listElems = document.querySelectorAll('.list__item');

let counter = 1;

for (const listElem of listElems) {
  listElem.innerHTML =  counter++;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">Пункт1</li>
  <li class="list__item">Пункт2</li>
  <li class="list__item">Пункт3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Если строки в массив загнать то можно  и от пример в цикл запихнуть

Comment: @Greg-- Да, так можно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот один из вариантов, пример:

```
listElems = document.querySelectorAll('.list__item');

newValues = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];

for (const key in listElems) {
  listElems[key].innerHTML =  newValues[key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.list__item').forEach((element, index) => {
   element.innerHTML = "new text " + index
})
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]